# Create an open polygon in Qt (line strips)

Tags: c++, qt, polygon

How can I create an **open** polygon, with using a **QVector** to initialise the polygon, in **Qt**?

**QPolygonF** will always close the Polygon and connect the last point with the first one.

Thank you for help

[Edit]

In **QGraphicsScene**

```
QVector<QPointF> test{{1,1},{100,1},{100,100}};
QPolygonF polygon(test);
addPolygon(polygon);
qDebug() << polygon.isClosed();
qDebug() << polygon.first() << polygon.last();
```

Output:

- a triangle, but I don't want a triangle. I want a line strip
- polygon.isClosed() = false
- First = 1,1
- Last = 100,100

Comment: just read docs http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpolygonf.html#isClosed or provide code which shows the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
QVector<QPointF> test{{1,1},{100,1},{100,100}};
QPainterPath path(test.front());
for (size_t i = 1; i < test.size(); ++i)
    path.lineTo(test[i]);
scene->addPath(path);
```

?

`QPolygonF` is a polygon, not it's unfinished line. It is drawn as a closed polygon with pen-defined line (can be invisible) filled by brush (also can be invisible).